# Having 1 Grails application for different environments (companies)

Tags: grails

I have a Grails application which is done for company A. Now there are some changes to be made to work for company B.
I don't want to duplicate whole project since it'll create issues later (code duplication, hard management, fixing bugs in both sides, etc.)
Instead I want to have same project with some company-specific code parts so I can do like "If company = A then ...".
The difference can be in class level (separate class file for each company) or only small part of code (same class with 80% same code + 20% company specific code).
What is the best way to have same Grails project with some configurable code parts so that I can build the project for company A or B separately?

Comment: I think you should go with multi tenant architecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

Disassemble your project into modules and/or plugins. There will be some common parts to both companies' apps, and extend the functionality to provide the company specifics.

You can also think of converting certain parts of your app into stand-alone (micro)services

Comment: It's hard to disassemble since:
1. I don't know in advance what will be changes for next company
2. changes can be very small code blocks inside whole common logic
For example in gsp file just have another line of data for a company which should not be in other company
So having each small part as a plugin or service will create huge amount of plugins or services which will affect readability.

Comment: There  are tons of approaches to solve that. One could be to copy you app A into B, change B appropriately and then compare both apps and see what common parts they share. Some parts can be extracted into "the core", others can be parametrized etc

Comment: Have to agree with injecteer. You're correct, you don't know in advance the changes for company 2, or 3, or n. Small differences perhaps you deal with in code via config values; bigger differences you can swap in a company-specific plugin via build config. You may be able to mitigate some future pain by refactoring into well-designed plugins now.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how intertwined the data sets are going to be. As well as how vastly I they are going to vary. If splitting into plugins is not possible and it is okay for data to be across same database and that a cat is still going to be a firm of a cat and not a dog. Then you could look at creating base classes then extending according to business having a save method for overall and then specific for extended values